# No valid data sent on customer export

Tags: magento-1.9

I tried to export customer data from admin but it throws this error "No valid data sent" I can export products without any issues. It was working absolutely fine before update from Magento version 1.9.0.1 to Version 1.9.2.3. can anyone point as to what might be causing the issue my exception log give the following error :

> Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(CASE WHEN
>   additional_table.is_system = 1 AND additional_table.is_visible = 0
>   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT
>   `main_table`.`attribute_id`, `main_table`.`entity_type_id`,
>   `main_table`.`attribute_code`, `main_table`.`attribute_model`,
>   `main_table`.`backend_model`, `main_table`.`backend_type`,
>   `main_table`.`backend_table`, `main_table`.`frontend_model`,
>   `main_table`.`frontend_input`, `main_table`.`frontend_label`,
>   `main_table`.`frontend_class`, `main_table`.`source_model`,
>   `main_table`.`is_required`, `main_table`.`is_user_defined`,
>   `main_table`.`default_value`, `main_table`.`is_unique`,
>   `main_table`.`note`, `additional_table`.`is_visible`,
>   `additional_table`.`input_filter`,
>   `additional_table`.`multiline_count`,
>   `additional_table`.`validate_rules`, `additional_table`.`is_system`,
>   `additional_table`.`sort_order`, `additional_table`.`data_model`,
>   `additional_table`.`is_used_for_customer_segment`,
>   `scope_table`.`website_id` AS `scope_website_id`,
>   `scope_table`.`is_visible` AS `scope_is_visible`,
>   `scope_table`.`is_required` AS `scope_is_required`,
>   `scope_table`.`default_value` AS `scope_default_value`,
>   `scope_table`.`multiline_count` AS `scope_multiline_count` FROM
>   `eav_attribute` AS `main_table`
>        INNER JOIN `customer_eav_attribute` AS `additional_table` ON additional_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id
>        LEFT JOIN `customer_eav_attribute_website` AS `scope_table` ON scope_table.attribute_id = main_table.attribute_id AND
>   scope_table.website_id = :scope_website_id WHERE
>   (main_table.entity_type_id = :mt_entity_type_id) AND (`(CASE WHEN
>   additional_table`.`is_system = 1 AND additional_table`.`is_visible = 0
>   THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)` = '0') AND (`main_table`.`frontend_input` !=
>   'hidden')' in /data/destamart/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php

Comment: did you get solution for this...

Comment: Nope :( I made a custom module to export all data

Comment: how you did that,

Comment: am using this,,,, this is right

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/l6jwzVk.png

Comment: what script you using for bulk export

Comment: may i know how many products you export at singe export

Comment: Willing to share custom module to export all data ??

Comment: ohk you can IM me your email id

Comment: shall we chat...

Comment: chat @ http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42689/no-valid-data-sent-on-customer-export

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42689/no-valid-data-sent-on-customer-export