# Var /export shows 403 forbidden error

Tags: magento-1.9

I created a module to custom export certain data from my site. The CSV is created in var/export. but when I try to give a link to download this file from server the link gives me 403 forbidden error. I see that the file has 777 permission. What can be the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's due to magento has security measures to disallow public to access `var` folder.

see `/var/.htaccess` file

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

I would recommend you to save your csv file else where. May be create a new folder in root and just save the file there.

**If you really want to save file in var**

Remove above code from `.htaccess` file. **But this is very bad practice.** You should <strike>avoid this</strike> **never do this**.

Thanks to @fschmengler - **As soon as var/cache is accssible, attackers can read sensitive configuration data. At most, add an exception for the CSV files in var/export**.

Comment: Thanks will try  to save it creating a folder in root. Thanks for the quick reply :)

Comment: Would be helpful if you accept my ans.

Comment: Thanks a ton.. it worked really well. I cant upvote it at this moment as I dont have enough reputation. Will you also look the following question. its bothering me for a long time now

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/103392/no-valid-data-sent-on-customer-export

Comment: ***Not only avoid it, NEVER do it.*** As soon as `var/cache` is accssible, attackers can read sensitive configuration data. At most, add an exception for the CSV files in `var/export`